# Seamless ContourPlot for a conditional function

Tags: plotting, conditional

When I try to create a ContourPlot of a continuous conditional function, Mathematica leaves a "seam" in between the two regions demarcated by the conditional. How do I fill this seam?

```
fn[x_, y_] := If[x < 2, y/x^2, y/(2 x)]
ContourPlot[fn[x, y], {x, 1.5, 2.5}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: The `PlotPoints -> 500` option helps.

Comment: add the option `Exclusions -> None`?

Comment: @kglr, that seems to solve the problem. Feel free to write up an answer to my trivial question and I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the option `Exclusions -> None` fixes the issue:

```
 ContourPlot[fn[x, y], {x, 1.5, 2.5}, {y, 0, 2}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much!